# Dynamic display of RadioButton control in ASP.NET mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am displaying controls dynamically. I am able to display all controls with appropriate values except for radio button. The radio button list is rendering correctly but the its value is not being checked.

```
foreach (var radio in item.RadioButtonList)
    {
        //Option 1

        @Html.RadioButton(radio.Text, radio.Checked) @:&nbsp; @radio.Text &nbsp;

        //Option 2

        @Html.RadioButton(name: radio.Text, value: radio.Checked, isChecked: radio.Checked)*@

        //Option 3

        <input type="radio" value="radio.Text"  checked="@radio.Checked"/> @:&nbsp; @radio.Text &nbsp;
     }
```

My model is

```
 public class FromElement
 { 
     public List<CBRBControl> RadioButtonList { get; set; }
 }

 public class CBRBControl
 {
     public string Text { get; set; }

     public bool Checked { get; set; }

     public string IsRadioChecked { get; set; }
 }
```

My controller

```
 public ActionResult FormDetails(int formID)
 {
            if (form.Field_Type_Name == "Radio Button")
            {
                radioList = new List<CBRBControl>();

                // For option 1 and 2

                radioList.Add(new CBRBControl
                {
                    Checked = true,
                    Text = "Radio Test 1"
                });

                radioList.Add(new CBRBControl
                {
                    Checked = false,
                    Text = "Radio Test 2"
                });

                // For option 3

                radioList.Add(new CBRBControl
                {
                    IsRadioChecked = "checked",
                    Text = "Radio Test 1"
                });

                radioList.Add(new CBRBControl
                {
                    Text = "Radio Test 2"
                });

                form.RadioButtonList = radioList;

            }
```

I tried working this using there method. In option 1 and 2 none of the radio button in the list is getting checked and in option 3 all the radio button is getting selected.

For option 1 the html generated is

```
<input id="Radio_Test_1" name="Radio Test 1" type="radio" value="True"> &nbsp; Radio Test 1 &nbsp;
<input id="Radio_Test_2" name="Radio Test 2" type="radio" value="False"> &nbsp; Radio Test 2 &nbsp;
```

For option 2 the html generated is

```
<input checked="checked" id="Radio_Test_1" name="Radio Test 1" type="radio" value="True"> &nbsp; Radio Test 1 &nbsp;
<input id="Radio_Test_2" name="Radio Test 2" type="radio" value="False"> &nbsp; Radio Test 2 &nbsp;
```

For option 3 the html generated is

```
<input type="radio" value="radio.Text" checked="checked"> &nbsp; Radio Test 1 &nbsp;
<input type="radio" value="radio.Text" checked=""> &nbsp; Radio Test 2 &nbsp;
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML generated from Helpers?

Comment: I am sorry i dont follow. Do you want me to go to view source and post the html??

Comment: Go to the browser, use page inspector and post the generated HTML! Just this RadioButton!

Comment: This may help http://www.techiesweb.net/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload from `RadioButton`. And you should provide the `Value` for this control as well.

Change your model to something like this:

```
public class CBRBControl
{
    //
    // Name should be unique, given that the HTML.RaadioButton,
    // will use this to generate the input attribute id, that
    // must be unique in the sabe HTML document
    //
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } 
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

And use the correct overload from Html.RadioButton like this:

```
@foreach (var radio in Model.RadioButtonList)
{
  @Html.RadioButton(radio.Name, radio.Value, radio.IsChecked) @:&nbsp; @radio.Text &nbsp;
}
```

The HTML generated will looks like:

```
<input id="radio_0" name="radio_0" type="radio" value="1" /> &nbsp; Radio Test 1 &nbsp;
<input checked="checked" id="radio_1" name="radio_1" type="radio" value="2" /> &nbsp; Radio Test 2 &nbsp;
```